# How to get full html source from jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I am using JSDOM to modify html text using jquery. After I modify it with jquery, i need the full html. I tried the code below, but it wob't give `<!Doctype html>` and all. How to get the full html?

mycode

```js
import jquery from "jquery";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";

function addElement(html){
      const { window } = new JSDOM(html);
      const $ = jquery(window);
      $("body").html("Hello SO!")
      return $("html").html()

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSDOM.serialize()` to get the full document.

In your case the code would be

```
function addElement(html){
      const { window } = new JSDOM(html);
      const $ = jquery(window);
      $("body").html("Hello SO!")
      return window.serialize();
}
```

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#serializing-the-document-with-serialize

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help

```
` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> ${document.head.getInnerHTML()} </head> 
    <body> ${document.body.getInnerHTML()} </body> 
</html> `
```